# Wallet balance showing as unconfirmed - SOLVED!

Tags: multibit

I'm using MultiBit and my wallet balance is showing as unconfirmed. The last transaction I made was a couple of months ago and seemed to be fine (https://blockchain.info/tx-index/25339607f1d5e3f36cd964554fd85c399c9359e58b169d6b7028b3627ef74f12).

When I try to make a payment with the unconfirmed funds I'm told "The error was insufficient money, missing XXX satoshis..."

I can see the correct balance in MultiBit but it is unconfirmed. The confirmed balance appears to be Zero. Any insight on what might have happened here or how I can fix it? I should say that I'm synced to the network and have 10 peers showing. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

My problem was easily solved, I simply had to Repair Wallet - an option in the Manage Wallet sidebar choice. All fixed!

Comment: Repair is not working. Neither is restore.

Answer (score 0):

As Multibit is unsupported, you'll have to move your wallet to Electrum software using these instructions.

https://bitcoinelectrum.com/restoring-your-multibithd-wallet-in-electrum/

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem. Bought bitcoins. After that I had to wait for enough confirmations, but I'm a newbie so I didn't know that. 
The solution for me was to wait.

Comment: I've downvoted this answer, because it suggests that the asker should wait for synchronization, however the asker states that his wallet is already synchronized.