# How do I restore a wallet from a backup file in MultiBit HD when you have the words and cloud backup?

Tags: wallet, multibit-hd, wallet-recovery

I have read this: [How do I restore a wallet from a backup file in MultiBit HD?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/38948/how-do-i-restore-a-wallet-from-a-backup-file-in-multibit-hd)

and have the words and mbhdxxxx.aes files in my cloud storage and the wallet password....

but the next button is not enabled when I enter the words:
[image]

**update**
I have had multibit before the hd client. I have a file like

> mbhd-8a659fc1-9acd420e-b2127154-b924c146-3f974bab-20150825115221.zip.aes

in the cloud and have found a file like

> mbhd-20160630143523.wallet.aes

I have used `decrypt_bitcoinj_seed` from github and entered my password and got 12 words to restore. The python script did not work with the long and older filename but did work with the short one. But when I have the words and try to recover it says: no datestamp found. When I use the words to continue and select a folder containing the old long file names it does proceed but with errors. I feel that I am getting closer. But I could use some pointers from people who have more experience with multibit hd and recovery.

[image]

I did found a folder in a backup on an external hdd which seems to work, but then I got:

[image]

I have had 2 wallets now in Multibit. I have selected the old one and waiting an eternity for the sync to finish. I have now my old wallet value as unconfirmed.
How can I fix this? I have read [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/47960/wallet-balance-showing-as-unconfirmed-solved). but there is no repair... only recover.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to write the words in correct order and with small letters, secondly use only spacebar button between them, DO NOT USE Enter button to go to the next line.

Comment: I copy pasted them in a notepad document (.txt) and copy pasted them back in to restore. So no typo's there and no newlines etc.

Comment: Enter them manualy and the lock icon will change and allow you to proceed further.

Comment: It is not the lock icon that is the problem. I clicked on it to make words invisible. It did not affect the "next" button. It stays disabled. Perhaps because the words are from an old multibit (hd) version? I still can not restore my wallet while having the words, the password and the cloud backup.

Comment: If the words were from another wallet but correct they should restore that said wallet.  How many words are you using, 12/16 or more ?. If you still have the wallet files and password you can look up wallet words using th [this link][1]
  [1]: https://github.com/gurnec/decrypt_bitcoinj_seed
After you the procedures written there, you'll be able to see the correct and only words for this exact wallet that you have and from there restore it.

Comment: 16 words. I have heard from Multibit HD that 16 words cannot be from multibit hd. So I have no clue how I have managed to get 16... perhaps before it was 'HD' ?

Comment: 16 words must be a different wallet because Multibthd allways used 12/18/24(i think..) words. It won't be and earlier version either because classic MB did not use wallet words. Try the tool I've linked before on your mbhd.wallet.aes file using your password as input value, after several minutes you'll see words which then you can use to restore wallet using only wallet words(without timestamp, password, etc) If you have more problems you can contact me directly at vanboohen(youknowwhat)mail ru.

Comment: Thank you @Vanboohen but it seems that not only my 16 words are failing, also the password is incorrect according to `decrypt_bitcoinj_seed.pyw` http://imgur.com/a/9K2NY I think I lost 36 euro :'(

Comment: @JPHellemons If you ever had to copy-paste the words, then you are basically violating every security precaution given to you automatically.

Comment: Living on the edge, yolo @Mark. I have the 12 words and the password to get them from the wallet.aes file but it says that there are no backups for 'this' wallet. But it's a backup from older wallet from older pc. it's asking for a datestamp now :S